# I'm new to Java - illegal start of expression and '(' and ')' expected

Tags: java

This is a grade checking program where the user is supposed to input a grade 0-100 and it says what grade they got. Ive looked elsewhere but can't find anything.

Thanks in advance

```
import java.util.*;

public class grading{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input grade");
    int grade = scan.nextInt();
    if (grade > 100){
      System.out.println("Sorry please put a number between 0-100");
    }
    else if (grade > 90){
      grade = "A";
      System.out.println("This student recieved " + grade " for his/her grade");
    }
    else if (grade > 75){
      grade = "B";
      System.out.println("This student recieved " + grade " for his/her grade");
    }
    else if (grade > 49){
      grade = "C";
      System.out.println("This student recieved " + grade " for his/her grade");
    }
    else{
      grade = "F";
      System.out.println("This student recieved " + grade " for his/her grade");
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: You're missing `+` after `grade` in the string concatenation expressions you're passing `println`.

Comment: Side note: It's "received" (e, then i). Also, in Java, the overwhelming convention is to capitalize class names, e.g., `Grading` rather than `grading`. In general they should be nouns as well.

Comment: You allow the user to enter negative values, but your message asks for values between 0-100.

Answer (score 3):

In each of your `println` statements, you're missing the `+` concatenation operator between `grade` and the final part of the string.

You also appear to be using `grade` for two different things, the integer input by the user and the string used in the concatenation.

The latter probably should be a distinct variable, like:

```
int grade = scan.nextInt();
String strGrade;

:

else if (grade > 90){
  strGrade = "A";
  System.out.println("This student received " + strGrade + " for his/her grade");
}
```

---

Also, for completeness when inputting a signed integer, you should probably make the first check handle negatives as well:

```
if ((grade < 0) || (grade > 100)) {
  System.out.println("Sorry please put a number between 0-100");
}
```

In addition, you can refactor out the duplicate code in each condition block, making for a more readable program:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Grading {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Get the grade.

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input grade");
    int grade = scan.nextInt();

    // Validate grade.

    if ((grade < 0) || (grade > 100)) {
      System.out.println("Sorry please put a number between 0-100");
    } else {
      // If valid, default to F, upgrade based on grade.

      String strGrade = "F";
      if      (grade > 90) strGrade = "A";
      else if (grade > 75) strGrade = "B";
      else if (grade > 49) strGrade = "C";

      // Output the results.

      System.out.println("This student received " + strGrade + " for his/her grade");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class grading{

public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please input grade");
int grade = scan.nextInt();
String gradeLevel = "";

if (grade > 100){
  System.out.println("Sorry please put a number between 0-100");
}
else if (grade > 90){
    gradeLevel = "A";
  System.out.println("This student recieved " + gradeLevel + " for his/her grade");
}
else if (grade > 75){
    gradeLevel = "B";
  System.out.println("This student recieved " + gradeLevel + " for his/her grade");
}
else if (grade > 49){
    gradeLevel = "C";
  System.out.println("This student recieved " + gradeLevel + " for his/her grade");
}
else{
    gradeLevel = "F";
  System.out.println("This student recieved " + gradeLevel + " for his/her grade");
}
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

In between the strings needed `+` for them to be connected